# How exact is DFT, really?

Tags: density-functional-theory, quantum-mechanics, quantum-dynamics

It is often claimed (e.g. [here](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/12/what-correlation-effects-are-included-in-dft/21#21?newreg=c5aca9e620cc4eb49d1048cf7465493a)), that Density Functional Theory is in principle exact. This seems to be a very strong statement to me.
Are all current limitations only of a technical nature rather than a fundamental?

There are a few reasons why I'm a bit skeptical:

- Lots  of work in condensed-matter physics is being done by people without DFT; e.g. related to topology, polarons, superconductivity...
- "All information is in the electron density". This means the single-particle reduced density matrix. As this is clearly a huge reduction from the exponentially large Hilbert space of the many-body system, I could argue that it makes DFT a semiclassical method?
- More recent numerical methods for quantum systems, such as tensor networks (MPS/DMRG/...) seem much more advanced (even if applied to simple setups), and even then they are only *perturbatively* exact, in bond dimension.

Am I missing something?

Comment: This might be a partial duplicate. Not voting to close since i do see some differences.  See this answer though. https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/a/533/697

Comment: @TristanMaxson thanks, will take a look

Comment: P.W. Anderson's paper "More is different" seems appropriate: https://science.sciencemag.org/content/177/4047/393

Comment: @user14717 thanks, very interesting. Your point is that DFT is virtually exact for the questions that it tries to answer; while useless for more fundamental research in quantum physics?

Comment: So what is wrong with the HK theorem?

Comment: @Wouter: Definitely not useless for fundamental research, but not the correct way to think about many problems in solid state.

Comment: @user14717 basically, HK tells us that the electron field is in a Fock state at every point, compared with for example a Gross-Pitaevskii equation which assumes a coherent state at every point?

Comment: ""All information is in the electron density". This means the single-particle reduced density matrix." Actually, it means the **diagonal** of the single-particle reduced density matrix - a much weaker property!

Comment: @SusiLehtola so essentially, DFT problems can be recast as a classical field theory. Then it's really striking that it is considered exact, while a GPE is only semiclassical.

Comment: The difference is that the Gross-Pitaevskii equation (GPE) comes from a mean-field wave function theory where all particles are placed on the lowest-lying orbital (it's the bosonic equivalent of Hartree-Fock). GPE disregards all correlation effects, which **are** included in density-functional theory *with the exact functional* (which we do not know).

Comment: All information *about the ground state* is in the *ground state* electron density, assuming that the external potential is local. This does not get you the many-body wavefunction, what it says is that it is not *necessary* to get the many-body wavefunction in order to describe all properties of the ground state. (For excited states, you need to invoke the Runge-Gross theorem and TD-DFT.)

Comment: @PhilHasnip Ok, I get that DFT does not address the excited states. But nevertheless, if 'properties' are synonym for 'all possible expectation values' , this means that it should give the ground state.
Btw, I think of two specific approximations that are assumed for DFT at the moment to solve the many-body problem: Born-Oppenheimer approximation (i.e. no nucleus-electron entanglement), and the instantaneous transmission of coulomb interaction. But probably these are often well justified

Comment: @wouter Yes exactly, all ground state properties are encoded in the density and a property-dependent universal functional. There is no fundamental assumption of Born-Oppenheimer or instantaneous Coulomb interaction, though they are ubiquitous in practice.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'll try to give a short but reasonably rigorous way of thinking about the exactness of density functional theory (DFT).

Consider $N$ electrons under the influence of a fixed external potential $v(\mathbf{r})$ for which the ground state electron density is $n(\mathbf{r})$. The external potential might be a sum of individual potentials from atomic nuclei, but it could also be something else.

This information, somewhat surprisingly, is sufficient for determining the *exact* quantum mechanical ground state energy of the interacting electron system (at least in principle). One conceptual approach involves the formula

$$
E_v[n] = \underset{\Psi \to n}{\mathrm{min}} \left\langle \Psi \right| \hat{T}+\hat{V}_{ee} \left| \Psi \right\rangle
    + \int \mathrm{d}\mathbf{r} \, v(\mathbf{r}) n(\mathbf{r}).
$$

The notation is a little abstract, so let's go term by term.

1. The left hand side, $E_v[n]$, just represents the energy of the electrons as a functional of the density $n(\mathbf{r})$, assuming a fixed $v(\mathbf{r})$.
2. The second part, $\underset{\Psi \to n}{\mathrm{min}} \left\langle \Psi \right| \hat{T}+\hat{V}_{ee} \left| \Psi \right\rangle$, is the most unfamiliar to newcomers. It says: (a) consider all admissible $N$-electron wave functions $\Psi$ that collapse to the prescribed electron density $n(\mathbf{r})$; (b) from these, choose the particular $\Psi$ that minimizes $\left\langle \Psi \right| \hat{T}+\hat{V}_{ee} \left| \Psi \right\rangle$, which is the sum of the kinetic ($T$) and electron-electron interaction ($V_{ee}$) energies; and (c) return this minimal $T+V_{ee}$ as the result.
3. The third part, $\int \mathrm{d}\mathbf{r} \, v(\mathbf{r}) n(\mathbf{r})$, is the interaction between the electrons and the external potential.

DFT involves a bit more than just this formula (which is due to Levy and Lieb building on work of Hohenberg and Kohn). But the formula underpins DFT's exactness.

The practical difficulties for DFT stem from the fact that $\underset{\Psi \to n}{\mathrm{min}} \left\langle \Psi \right| \hat{T}+\hat{V}_{ee} \left| \Psi \right\rangle$ is conceptually elegant, but nearly impossible to implement in most cases (having [NP-like complexity](https://www.nature.com/articles/nphys1370)). The panoply of density functional approximations provide alternatives to implementing this term directly. They are often sufficiently accurate for answering questions in physics, chemistry, and materials science, but not always.

Comment: +1. Kudos for a fast answer! It will help the question become and HNQ which is what our site needs to grow!

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Basically, my main objection comes down to the following: if there is no fundamental limit to how well n(r) can be known, than one day a clever prodigy can write it down exactly. But it seems to me that, if the orbitals are sufficiently localized, the molecule can also in principle be mapped with a Jordan-Wigner like transformation to an Ising-like spin glass. And finding the ground state of this is an untrivial endeavour in quantum information. So basically, you would have proved that P=NP.

Comment: Or is the thing that you get with DFT approaches a good estimate of the ground state energy, but not the ground state wavefunction itself?

Comment: Aha, maybe it's far more obvious (almost tautological) in 2nd quantization; which naturally allows for a spatial description in terms of density and phase. If there are no magnetic fields involved, all phase differences would cost energy, so only the density remains?

Comment: I think your P=NP objection is understandable, and I added a link to a paper exploring this idea in more detail! But the argument isn't that DFT provides a free lunch, only that DFT is an exact restatement of the original problem that, when implemented approximately, has proven to be quite useful.

Comment: The problem of finding the many-body wavefunction is NP; however, the HK theorem says you don't *need* the many-body wavefunction in order to describe the ground state.